# Get arraylist of image file object from arraylist of url in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-bitmap, android-file

My Objective is:

- Need to get image path from api call in url string like: "http://serverpath.com/projectname/images/imagename.png"
- Need to send image path to api call in file object.
  So I am taking ArrayList only.

I should show image path in imageview when its converted into file object.

I am trying with some solutions with different file object are:

```
File f=null;
    URL url = new URL(info4Model.getExternal_photos().get(position).getImage_path());
        try {
         //   f = new File(url.toURI());//java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI:
            //f = new File(url.getPath());//  not showing file object in imageview
            //f = new File(url.getFile());// not showing file object in imageview
            f = getFileFromBitmap(info4Model.getExternal_photos().get(position).getImage_path());
             //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException , AsyncTask option left only?

        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
///////////////////////////////////
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmapFrmUrl = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmapFrmUrl;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
File getFileFromBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromURL(url);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMddhhmmss");
    String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
    File imageFile = new File(filesDir, dateAsString + ".png");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageFile;
}
```

Here all the file objects are showing failure results in comments after the statement.

Answer (score 1):

If u get the image url..from api...

Then,
Uae picasso for loading ur image into imageview like..
Picasso.with(acticityname.this)

.load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")

.into(imageView);

And

For api to load your image path..
You have to use multipart..

For that..

File file= new File(ur image path);
FileBody a1=new FileBody(file);

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();  mpEntity.addPart("param name", a1);

Hope,you may get help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FileModel {
    File Url;
    File path;
    File file;
    File bitMap;

    public File getUrl() {
        return Url;
    }

    public void setUrl(File url) {
        Url = url;
    }

    public File getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(File path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getBitMap() {
        return bitMap;
    }

    public void setBitMap(File bitMap) {
        this.bitMap = bitMap;
    }
    }  

  ArrayList<FileModel> fileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
        File f=null;
        URL url = new URL(info4Model.getExternal_photos().get(position).getImage_path());
        try {
            f = new File(url.toURI());//java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI:
            fileModel.setUrl(f);
            f = new File(url.getPath());//  not showing file object in imageview
            fileModel.setPath(f);
            f = new File(url.getFile());// not showing file object in imageview
            fileModel.setFile(f);
            f = getFileFromBitmap(info4Model.getExternal_photos().get(position).getImage_path());
            fileModel.setBitMap(f);
            //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException , AsyncTask option left only?

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fileArrayList.add(fileModel);
```

finally  File arraylist is ready to use.

I hope it's helpful for you ,,,!

Comment: Thanks, but all the objects have commented results as you can see. So My question to get from all these no one single File object is working.

Comment: you need to crate a one model class then put all the values in model and and model in ArrayList ...!